# Can't compile grails Tomcat plugin

Tags: grails, netbeans, classpath

I'm using Netbeans to build a Grails app, while I have used this fine before on this new computer I can not get even the basic project to compile and run. I am getting errors around compiling the Tomcat plugin. If I uninstall the plugin it and use Jetty instead it will compile but the project isn't set up for Jetty and is missing files.

Below is the error I'm getting I'm thinking it is some issue with my classpath but I just don't know where to start any help would be much appreciated.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper

**Update** I have tried grails clean, and used both grails 1.2.0 and 1.3.1

**Update** The project I've tried with tomcat is the base project generated by grails.

Comment: Providing more details would be helpful to answer this question. For example what version of Grails do you use? Did you already try a `grails clean` before?

Comment: I have tried both grails 1.2.0 and 1.3.1 I get the same error, I did the grails clean and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "but the project isn't set up for Jetty and is missing files." what do you have in there that maybe clashing with Tomcat? It sounds like you must be using some specific tomcat functionality.

Comment: I have tried just the basic project generated from scratch with both 1.2.0 and 1.3.1, either of these used on another computer will both run correctly. I tried uninstalling the tomcat plugin and then installing jetty and I wasn't able to set that up to run instead. 

Using another computer that allows it to work makes me think it is some classpath or other variable setting somewhere but I don't know where to look.